# mysql left join and order by

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by, left-join

hi i have to different tables m_mp and m_answer
both have m_date and m_mdate which fills with time() function i want to select both entries but order by date

example:

first table: 'some text','6464647776'
second table 'some answer','545454545'

so i want to show first second table and then the first one

this is the code im using:

```
SELECT r.*,u.* 
FROM `mensajes` as r 
LEFT JOIN `m_answer` as u on r.id = u.id_m 
WHERE r.id  = '1' 
ORDER BY m_date
```

and then display the result of each table using while-loop

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: im making a messaging system with replies so i want to show the original message and then the replies ordering by date

Comment: It looks like your query could do that. What does a test in MySQL show you?

Comment: http://prntscr.com/8hlt98 this

Answer (score 0):

I guess I get what you want to do.

You may force both grouping and ordering using ORDER BY, like this:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/373d65/9

I know the solution is not optimal in terms of speed, but, given proper indices, I suspect performance to be acceptable, unless you are already aiming for millions of messages; when that time comes, you would like to either properly GROUPBY, or make subsequent queries for just the recently answered questions from the current page.

Comment: im making a messaging system with replies so i want to show the original message and then the replies ordering by date using while-loop